# ¿Es lo mismo isset($var1) que (!$var1)?

Tags: php

¿Es lo mismo `isset($var1)` que `(!$var1)`?. Es decir, en los ejemplos que a continuacion pongo parece funcionar igualmente: detectar si una variable está definida. Si no son lo mismo ¿Cuando se utiliza uno y otro?

```
<?php 
  $var1;  
  if(!$var1){
    echo "si";
  }
?>
```

Ejemplo de lo mismo con isset

```
<?php
  $var1;
  if(isset($var1)){
    echo "si";
  }
?>
```

Este ejemplo contiene tanto isset como ! . Como vereis cuando se usa el ! not comprueba si existe un controlador pero... que pasa cuando no existe. ¿Mandará un error de "undefined variable" de PHP?

```
class Request{
  private $_controlador;
  private $_metodo;
  private $_argumentos;

  public function __construct(){
    if(isset($_GET['url'])){
      $url = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
      $url = explode('/', $url);
      $url = array_filter($url);

      //toma array url y coge el primer elemento y lo asigna a _controlador.
      //Lo mismo con _metodo y argumentos.
      $this->_controlador = strtolower(array_shift($url));
      $this->_metodo = strtolower(array_shift($url));
      $this->_argumentos = $url;
    }

    if(!$this->_controlador){
      $this->_controlador = DEFAULT_CONTROLLER;
    }

    if(!$this->_metodo){
      $this->_metodo = 'index';
    }

    if(!isset($this->_argumentos)){
      $this->_argumentos = array();
    }
  }

  public function getControlador()
  {
    return $this->_controlador;
  }

  public function getMetodo()
  {
    return $this->_metodo;
  }

  public function getArgs()
  {
    return $this->_argumentos;
  }

}
```

Comment: Buenas Ricardo. ¿Has leido la documentacion del metodo `isset`  y el operador `!` ? Qué no te ha quedado claro? Detalla más la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Creo entender ambos. Mi pregunta es si en ambos casos lo que se hace es detectar si la variable esta definida. Algunas veces veo que en un mismo codigo se usa indistitantament uno y otro y esto me lleva a pensar que quizá no tengan el mismo uso.

Comment: @RicardoKra ¿Y qué pasa si no tienes la variable $var1 escrita justo antes de comprobar si existe? Algunas veces envías desde un formulario <form> un valor y lo quieres recoger en otra página distinta, para eso puedes usar el isset, te comprueba si el valor enviado ha llegado a la otra página.

Comment: Si en un `<form action="/page2.php" method="get">` tienes un `<input type="text" value="HOLA" name="saludo" />`, al pulsar en el botón de enviar el formulario, en page2.php puedes hacer `if(isset($_GET["saludo"]){ }` y compruebas si se ha enviado el "HOLA" del input y se ha recibido en esa página

Comment: Por favor, ver nuevo cambio en pregunta. Existe un ! not para ver si controlador existe. Si no existe ¿esto daría un error de undefined varialble en php?

Answer (score 9):

Pues no, no es lo mismo.

`isset()` comprueba que la variable existe, mientras que `!` solo comprueba que el valor sea "falso".

Es decir, si haces un `isset()` a una variable que no existe, este te devolvera falso, pero si haces `!variableInexistente` te vas a comer un error de PHP por usar una variable no definida.

Comment: Además de eso isset verifica que el valor no sea NULL

Comment: Si yo pongo: $var1;


if(!$var1){
echo "si";
} esto me muestra "si" en php tester pero al mismo tiempo me manda un mensaje de error NOTICE Undefined variable: var1 on line number 5. ¿Como se puede manejar sin que lanze el error?

Comment: Tienes que asignarle algún valor a la variable, si va a ser algo "vacio" es buena idea que la definas de esta manera: `$var1 = false` o `$var1 = null`

Answer (score 2):

La función  `isset` y el operador de negación `!` no son lo mismo ni tienen el mismo propósito.

### Función: isset()

> **Determina si una variable está definida y no es NULL**, si son pasados varios parámetros, entonces isset() devolverá TRUE únicamente si todos los parámetros están definidos.
>
> Esta función retorna un valor boleano, es decir TRUE o FALSE

### Operador lógico: !

> **Niega el valor boleano**, es decir si el valor es TRUE lo convierte a FALSE, si el valor es FALSE lo convierte a TRUE.

---

Cuando utilizamos el condicional `if` este termina haciendo una reducción  de las premisas a valores boleanos.

Vemos tus ejemplos:

**Ejemplo 1** (Negación):

```
// Esta variable no será considerada definida mientras no le asignemos un valor
// es decir mientras no la inicialicemos
// si es utilizada será reemplazada por un valor del tipo especial NULL
$var1;

// un valor no definido es igual a NULL si se utiliza en algún lugar
// aquí $var1 es convertido en boleano 
// La conversión de un NULL a boleano da como resultado false
if(!$var1){ // esto es igual a if(!FALSE) o lo que es lo mismo if(TRUE)
    echo "si";
  }
// RESULTADO: si
// esto también nos generará un error de variable indefinida
// ya que en ningún momento se verifica si esta definida o no, y tratamos de usarla
```

**Ejemplo 2** (isset):

```
<?php
$var1; // como dijimos esto se considera una variable no definida
// sabemos que isset retorna FALSE si una variable no está definida o es NULL
if(isset($var1)){ // es igual a if(FALSE)
    echo "si";
}
```

**Ejemplo 3** (clase):

El tercer caso `$var` es una propiedad de una clase, en este caso la variable sí se considera definida aun cuando no le asignemos un valor, por defecto su valor es del tipo especial NULL, al definir propiedades en una clase estas pueden o no ser inicializadas en la misma definición, vemos un ejemplo:

```
<?php

class MiClase{
  // La propiedad $var si se considera definida 
  // aun que no haya sido inicializada
  public $var; // esto es igual a public $var = NULL;
  
    public function dump() {
        var_dump($this);
    }
    
    public function existe() {
        if(isset($this->var)) {
            echo 'Existe y no es NULL (TRUE)';
        } else {
            echo 'NO existe o es NULL (FALSE)';
        }
    }

    public function negacion() {
        if(!$this->var) {
            echo 'if evalua !NULL (TRUE) ';
        }
    }
}

// instanciamos la clase
$obj = new MiClase();

// vemos que la propiedad $var vale NULL
$obj->dump(); // object(MiClase)#1 (1) { ["var"]=> NULL }
// isset
$obj->existe(); // NO existe o es NULL (FALSE)
// negacion (!)
$obj->negacion(); // if evalua !NULL (TRUE)

if(property_exists('MiClase', 'var')) {
    echo 'La propiedad $var existe en MiClase (TRUE)';
} // Imprime: La propiedad $var existe en MiClase (TRUE)

?>
```

---

Documentación:

Función `isset()` http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php

Operadores lógicos http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php

Boleano http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.boolean.php

Propiedades http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: Gracias Xerif. ¿Puedes ver segunda parte de la pregunta con nuevo codigo referente a lo que estamos hablando? Alli verás que se verifica si la variable "_controlador" es true o false ¿verdad? Esa variable se toma de la url, que se trocea y se va sacando el valor de _controlador, _metodo y _args. Centremonos es _controlador. Se comprueba si es true o false pero, en caso de que no se muestre  en la url, el valor será false y esto llevará a que php lanzé un error por variable indefinida ¿verdad? ¿No es poco raro esta forma de comprobar si se pasa por url el valor de _controlador? ¿Tu que opinas?

Comment: @RicardoKra A ver, no termino de entender lo que me quieres decir, en el segundo caso `_controlador` es una propiedad de una clase que aun que no se le asigne un valor si se considera definida y por defecto tendrá un valor NULL, por lo que si llamas a dicha propiedad no obtendras ningun error por variable indefinida, aunque las variables y las propiedades de una clase son practicamente lo mismo, tienen algunos matices.

Comment: Si, seguro sea eso, que sea una propiedad de clase y por eso no da error. Gracias!

Comment: @RicardoKra edite la pregunta añadiendo el caso de las propiedades de clase. Un saludo.